# C# unity rigidbody 2D restrict movement to only one axis at the same time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controls

I am making a 2d game and i had a problem with controls. I am trying to make it so player can only move horizontally and vertically, and if i press 2 control buttons at the same time, for example w and d, make player move in direction which second button u pressed coresponds, it works fine with Vertical, but if I press for example d while moving up it just keeps moving upwards, while it has to move right. Here is the code:

````
  {
   public Vector2 movement;
   void Update()
   {
     movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
     movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
     if (movement.y != 0)
     {
         movement.x = 0;
     }
     if (movement.x != 0)
     {
         movement.y = 0;
   }
  }```
````

Comment: Well in that case `if (movement.y != 0) { movement.x = 0; }` kicks in and you keep moving only vertically

Comment: and how do i fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to set a flag indicating which key (or axis) received the input first. In this case you have to store this information between the frames.
A single boolean would not suffice in this case afaik (since it only represents two states), but we can simply use enums to provide the necessary container to store our information:

```
   // States/Prio of (first) user input
   public enum PrioritisedInput
   {
    None,
    XAxis,
    YAxis
   }
  
   public PrioritisedInput prioInput = PrioritisedInput.None;

   public Vector2 movement;
   void Update()
   {
     movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
     movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

     if(movement.y == 0 && movement.x == 0)
     {
      // Reset value if no input was detected
      prioInput = PrioritisedInput.None;         
     }
     else if(movement.y != 0 && movement.x == 0)
    {
     // YAxis input, but no xAxis input. Prio YAxis
     prioInput =  PrioritisedInput.YAxis;
    }
    else if(movement.y == 0 && movement.x != 0)
    {
     // YAxis input, but no xAxis input. Prio XAxis
     prioInput =  PrioritisedInput.XAxis;
    }
    else if(movement.y != 0 && movement.x != 0 && prioInput == PrioritisedInput.None)
    {
     // What happens if both axis receive an input the same frame?
     // Maybe just prio x axis
     prioInput =  PrioritisedInput.XAxis;
    }    

     if (prioInput == PrioritisedInput.XAxis)
     {
         movement.y = 0;
     }
     else if(prioInput == PrioritisedInput.YAxis)
     {
         movement.x = 0;
     }
```

read more on enums: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum

Comment: What are the errors? Obviously syntax may not be 100% without ide or anything. Please share error messages otherwise I cannot help further

Comment: I can send screenshots but my VS is in Russian.

Comment: Do not really know what to say. Maybe copy paste the code? Or do you use like russian letters and stuff? Then I am not able to help you with your code. If you could set Visual studio to english, and copy paste the error message would also help

Comment: Most of them were on me but 1 still left CS0103 name "None" does not exist in this context          else if (movement.y != 0 && movement.x != 0 && prioInput == None)

Comment: Yea well, as i said, it may not be 100% syntax correct. If you just copy all code, and get an error and just resign without thinking yourself, you wont find a 100% fit solution for just your needs.

Check this I wrote:     `else if(movement.y != 0 && movement.x != 0 && prioInput == None)`
obviously "None" does not exist. It needs to be PrioritisedInput.None

Comment: Thank you, everything is working fine now!

Comment: Glad to help you